# Unable to uninstall github for mac

Tags: github, github-for-mac

Github for mac is completely not working. It just brings up an xcode window with a 9 month old file in text editor.

So I tried to uninstall it using this gist:

https://gist.github.com/naomik/11245234

but it did not help: every time I go to a github link the same xcode useless window comes up.

[image]

When I click on Launch Application then the empty xcode window comes up.
If I click on Do Nothing then .. well nothing happens (it does not navigate to the github page !!)

Help needed badly on this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uninstall with CleanMyMac? I think it should clear all depending files so i think it can help.